# How to scan barcode in JPEG format with zbar in Linux?

Tags: embedded, scanner, jpeg, png

I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.10.24). Now I am trying to use `zbar-0.23` to scan barcodes in JPEG format, but I don't know how to do that.

There is an example/scan_image.c, which can scan barcodes in `PNG` format, but my barcodes are all in `JPEG` format.

So how to scan the barcodes in `JPEG` format with `zbar`? What are the interfaces in `libzbar` can be used to do the JPEG barcode scanning?

Comment: You should pester your HW vendor for an updated BSP. 5.10 LTS is at subversion 212 now, so you are missing about 3 years of security updates on that 5.10.24 install. Or better yet, respin all this based on a less ancient 6.1, or 6.6 kernel

Comment: OK, that is a good reminder. I will chat with HW vendor on the SDK updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zbarimg program uses imagemagick to read the images.

See the code here: https://github.com/herbyme/zbar/blob/068c810f75994b61ab9edc689650d09a0fc78bf9/zbarimg/zbarimg.c#L127

That deals beautifully with jpeg and a very large range of image files (unless you disabled jpeg explicitly when building imagemagick). So, I don't know what exactly you're doing, but it seems like a solved problem!

Comment: OK, I did notice there is a folder of `zbarimg` in the source code of `zbar`. I tried to enable its compiling by changing the Makefile, but it reported missing of some symbols.  So as you answered, it depends on imagemagick. I will try that by building `imagemagick` firstly then build `zbarimg` to try. Do you know the resource requirement using zbarimg with imagemagick, if the performance is OK for a small embedded system? I will vote for your answer 2 days later.

Comment: I just tried rebuilding `zbarimg` with `imagemagick` enabled, it worked with a barcode in JPEG format. I already voted for this answer.